# Using TableView with generic object properties

Tags: java, tableview, javafx-8

I have a dozen of parameters i want to display throught a javafx application. I just pick TableView to render these parameters.

Here is how theses parameters looks like :

```
public abstract class AbstractParameter<T> {

    private String myKey;
    private ObjectProperty<T> myValue = new SimpleObjectProperty<T>()
    private boolean constantValue;


    public AbstractParameter<T>(){
             //...
    }

    ObjectProperty<T> property(){ 
         return property;
    }

}
```

Note here that a have multiple subclasses such as StringParameter, IntegerParameter, LongParameter, BooleanParameter, ect...

I'm using that approach because some of the params are defined/updated during runtime

Now here is my ParametersUIController

```
public Class ParametersUiController {

@FXML
private TableView<AbstractParameter<?>> paramsTable;
@FXML
private TableColumn<AbstractParameter<?>, String> paramKeyCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<AbstractParameter<?>, String> paramValueCol;
@FXML
private TableColumn<AbstractParameter<?>, Boolean> paramConstantValueCol;


private ObservableList<AbstractParameter<?>> paramsData = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

/**
* Just add some sample data in the constructor.
*/
public PersonTableController() {
  /* getting a list of params for a service 
     the params are defined in list
  */
  for(AbstractParameter<?> param : rawData)
      paramsData.add(param);
  }

/* I cast the value type to string always */

pValueCol.setCellValueFactory(new Callback<CellDataFeatures<AbstractParameter<?>, String>, ObservableValue<String>>() {
         public ObservableValue<String> call(CellDataFeatures<AbstractParameter<?>, String> param) {
             return new SimpleStringProperty(param.getValue().property().get().toString());
         }
      });

}
```

I'm wordering is there any other proper way to display generic types T without casting a defined paramter at runtime with String every time ?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I editted the question to be more specific and clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this:

```
pValueCol.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory("generic"));
```

and create a method like this in your model:

```
ObjectProperty<T> genericProperty(){ 
         return property;
}
```

The statement `new PropertyValueFactory("generic")` look for a method in your model named `genericProperty`. It can return the generic value wrapped in an `ObjectProperty<T>`.